# arduino resets when switching on relay

Tags: arduino, relay

Good day everyone

I have the Atmega328P-AU on a PCB (Controller IC used in arduino nano).
I have made the connections as shown in the arduino website for bootloading and uploading the code. This part works fine.

I have a relay connected to the arduino through an npn and pnp transistors. The relay is required to switch on an SBC(Single Board Computer). Arduino is running a basic code right now during testing. In setup it creates a delay of 30 seconds then switches on the relay to power on the SBC. Once the arduino reaches the line to power on the relay, the relay gets switched on, power is provided to the SBC, and then immediately arduino gets reset and then the entire cycle continues.

The code being used is given below

```
void setup() 
{
pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(5,0);
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Start");
delay(10000);
Serial.println("Pass1");
digitalWrite(5,1);
Serial.println("Pass2");
}

void loop() 
{

}
```

I have also attached the basic circuit diagram[image]
The dc jack is connected to a 6V 2A adapter

Can anyone guide me to make the necessary changes so that my circuit will work

Also the PCB is designed to fit onto the SBC as a shield. The setup doesn't work while connected as shield. But it will work when connecting the PCB to SBC using jumper wires

Thank you for your time

Comment: Does your drawing package allow you to create a proper schematic (using PNP and NPN transistor symbols, resistor symbols, etc.) instead of a wiring diagram? Then we can see the *schema* of your system.

Comment: You should not need two transistors but it's unclear if anyone willing be willing to follow that pictorial to see how you are using them.  Beware you cannot really switch power to the SBC if it has any electrical connection to the Arduino without obeying the rules about signals on unpowered parts.  Does the problem occured with no sbc but just the relay?  What **exactly** is the power supply?  You do realize 6v is too low for the Arduino regulated input and too high for the unregulated?

Comment: Note that you really should not be powering your  Atmega328P-AU with a 6V supply. These devices operate correctly with a 5V supply.

Comment: Now that you have attempted to make a circuit schematic you need to take a careful look at the NPN and PNP transistors. You have both connected wrong in this first attempt at your schematic.

Comment: I have updated the circuit to a schematic circuit as requested by 'Transistor'

Comment: To answer 'Chris Stratton', Initially I was using only NPN to control the relay, but for some reason it did not have stable switching for some of the relays. From then I started using 2 transistors. As I new to this, I didn't understand the next part. Hope you can elaborate. 
"Michael Karas", I know that the controller will work well at 5V, but I need a 5V 2A power supply for my SBC, and 6V 2A is what I could get. Also thanks for highlighting my mistake. I believe I have fixed it right now.

Comment: @Rakshith Narun By the way, using @ allows you to tag people. Quoting the name doesn't provide a notification. Also, tangentially related, but Fritzing is famous for being a very good program which helps people learn the worst possible habits for writing schematics, which are then in general completely undecipherable. :(

Comment: @AndrejaKo Thanks for teaching me how to tag people. Also thanks for suggesting me use a different software for making schematics

Comment: This circuit is a disaster.  Get yourself a regulated 5v supply, look up how to use an NPN transistor as a "low side switch", and realize that schematics are not wires going every which way but drawn in an organized fashion with some geometric consistency to positive vs. negative supplies.

Answer (score 1):

If you have wired this all up with long wires to a proto plug board then the problem that you have with your circuit is power and ground not staying at the correct voltage at the moment that the relay turns on. The surge current that flows when the relay coil is first energized and the current starts to charge the capacitors on the SBC can be enough to cause a glitch or short duration droop of the 6V supply. It is equally possible that the ground is being pulled up for the same reasons.

The power/ground glitches are causing your MCU to generate an internal reset signal which makes it start its program over again.

There are some things you can do to improve the situation:

1. Provide for a very good central point ground bus with the shortest wires possible from each GND connection to this common GND point.
2. You need to provide bypass capacitors between VDD and GND right at the MCU. something like a pair of capacitors of 0.1uF and 10uF would be a good start.
3. Provide a good bulk energy storage capacitor between the emitter of the 2N3906 and the GND side of the relay coil. A 22uF capacitor would be a good start here. The capacitor would supply the surge current for the relay coil  rather than pulling the power rail down and/or the ground up.
4. Provide a good bulk energy storage capacitor between the Common connection of the relay and the ground bus. This will provide the surge current for the SBC load at time that the relay first turns on. Size of this capacitor really depends upon the amount of bulk capacitance on the SBC but it could be that a suitable starting value would be in the range of 470uF to 1000uF.

Comment: I have made a PCB for the shown circuit. This PCB is like a shield for the SBC. Meaning it will sit directly on the SBC. For the point 2, are the capacitors in parallel or series. For point 3, Emitter of the 2N3906(PNP) is connected to Vcc. This would mean I am going to put 22uF across Vcc and GND. Can you confirm this. Thank you

Comment: @RakshithNarun - For point 2 the capacitors are in parallel. For point 3 the capacitor is between VCC and GND. In fact all the capacitors I suggested are between VCC and GND. Key difference is that all are placed so that they serve the current demands if each specific load.